Graph Neural Network (GNN) (2)
This is an implementation of a graph neural network.
Edges are represented by an egde-list.
### GNN taking edge list as an input

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Sample data
nodes_data = {
    'node_id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    'age': [25, 30, 22, 28, 35],
    'gender': [0, 1, 0, 1, 0],  # 0: Male, 1: Female
    'occupation': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]  # Encoded occupations
}

edges_data = {
    'edge_id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    'source': [1, 2, 3, 4, 1],
    'target': [2, 3, 4, 5, 3],
    'relationship_strength': [0.8, 0.6, 0.7, 0.9, 0.5]
}

nodes_df = pd.DataFrame(nodes_data)
edges_df = pd.DataFrame(edges_data)

# Convert to zero-based indexing
nodes_df['node_id'] = nodes_df['node_id'] - 1
edges_df['source'] = edges_df['source'] - 1
edges_df['target'] = edges_df['target'] - 1

# Feature and target preparation
features = nodes_df[['age', 'gender', 'occupation']].to_numpy()
num_features = features.shape[1]
num_nodes = features.shape[0]

# Assume some target labels for demonstration
target_labels = np.array([0, 1, 0, 1, 0])  # Example target labels (e.g., binary classification)

# Graph construction
graph = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(edges_df, source='source', target='target')
adj_matrix = nx.adjacency_matrix(graph).todense()

class GraphConvLayer(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, output_dim, **kwargs):
        super(GraphConvLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.output_dim = output_dim

    def build(self, input_shape):
        print("build() input_shape:", input_shape)
        self.kernel = self.add_weight(
            shape=(input_shape[0][-1], self.output_dim),
            initializer='glorot_uniform',
            name='kernel'
        )

    def call(self, inputs):
        features, adj_matrix = inputs
        adj_matrix_dense = tf.convert_to_tensor(adj_matrix, dtype=tf.float32)  # Ensure adj_matrix is dense
        output = tf.matmul(adj_matrix_dense, features)
        output = tf.matmul(output, self.kernel)
        return output

def create_gnn_model(input_shape, output_dim, num_nodes):
    features_input = keras.Input(shape=(num_nodes, input_shape), name='features')
    adj_matrix_input = keras.Input(shape=(num_nodes, num_nodes), name='adj_matrix')

    x = GraphConvLayer(16)([features_input, adj_matrix_input])
    x = layers.ReLU()(x)
    x = GraphConvLayer(output_dim)([x, adj_matrix_input])

    return keras.Model(inputs=[features_input, adj_matrix_input], outputs=x)

gnn_model = create_gnn_model(num_features, 2, num_nodes)
gnn_model.compile(
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01),
    loss=keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
    metrics=[keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy(name='acc')]
)

# Data preparation for training
adj_matrix_input = np.array(adj_matrix).astype(np.float32)
features_input = features.astype(np.float32)

# Expand dimensions to match the input shape (batch size, num_nodes, num_features)
features_input = np.expand_dims(features_input, axis=0)
adj_matrix_input = np.expand_dims(adj_matrix_input, axis=0)
target_labels = np.expand_dims(target_labels, axis=0)  # Expand dimensions of target_labels to match the batch size

print("features_input shape:", features_input.shape)
print("adj_matrix_input shape:", adj_matrix_input.shape)
print("target_labels shape:", target_labels.shape)

# Train the model
history = gnn_model.fit(
    x=[features_input, adj_matrix_input],
    y=target_labels,
    epochs=100,
    batch_size=1,
    validation_split=0  # Set validation_split to 0
)

plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
plt.xlabel('Epochs')
plt.ylabel('Loss')
plt.show()

plt.plot(history.history['acc'])
plt.xlabel('Epochs')
plt.ylabel('Accuracy')
plt.show()


```


This is substantially the same code as from
this morning's earlier submission.
It adopts none of the recommended changes.
Node adjacency is represented in a slightly
different way, yet none of the common logic
has been factored out and reused.
We see no """docstrings""" explaining
caller's responsibility and expected output.
If there is some improvement in this version 2,
I am not yet seeing it.
